# I need to save wordpress Dynamically loaded web html pages using python code

Tags: python, wordpress, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have deployed WordPress inside my localhost and I am using selenium web driver to automatically navigate to each and every link. I need to save each dynamically loaded html pages of that WordPress site using a python script.Please help me. Here I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get a plain HTML version of your wordpress site, you'll usually not need to go at it via a full browser, as very few wordpress sites are ajax-heavy.

Give Webhttrack (or plain httrack) a try.
Install `webhttrack` on your machine and run it via the menu (It's usually found under Internet / Network) or terminal (by simple running "webhttrack").
It will start a local webserver and point your browser to a web interface which you can use to setup your download project. Once you run it, you will find a plain copy of the wordpress site in ~/websites/.